# How to change text in div while executing setInterval function using highcharts-ng with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, highcharts-ng

I have a `controller` which has the following call :

```
userFactory.getScore(_token, function (response) {
    $scope.scores = response;
    renderCharts(response,$scope);
    score.resolve();
});
```

here, `userFactory` is a factory.

Now in my `function renderCharts` :

```
function renderCharts(response,$scope) {

    $scope.current_target_label = {"label":"Current Score"};
    // Highcharts config object declaration here

    setInterval(function($scope) {
        // Logic to update highchart
        $scope.current_target_label = {"label":"Target Score"};
    }

}
```

Following assignment doesn't update the value in ng-bind in the `html` view : `$scope.current_target_label = {"label":"Target Score"};`

I am surely doing something wrong, appreciate for any pointers so as to what to do to get the value of text of `div` updated in the `html` view ?

Comment: Will you please share your complete code or create a fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval` is *outside* of angulars *$digest-cycle*, so angular will not update data-bindings. You could use [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) but, I'd say, that's bad practice. Better use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) or [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). Wich will trigger the *$digest-cycle*. E.g:

```
function renderCharts(response,$scope) {
    // ...

    $interval(function() {
        // Logic to update highchart
        $scope.current_target_label = {"label":"Target Score"};
    }, delay);
}
```

Notes:

- You'll, of course, need to inject the service where you need it.
- In your original code you used `setInterval(function($scope) {`. `$scope` here will probably be undefined, and thus shadow the outer `$scope` variable.